# Deploy backend side

Tags: mysql, laravel, flutter, dart, deployment

I have created a `Flutter` app with `Laravel/MySQL` as the backend side.
I've got my `api's` using the `localhost:port` .

Everything works fine , using `Xampp`.

Now , as you may have noticed this my first time trying to deploy my work , how can I deploy my server side(Laravel,MySQL) to any paid service ?

Then, how can I change the `api` from localhost to an actual address valid everywhere using the app that will be deployed to `Google Playstore` .

Answer (score 2):

you can use any hosting service like heroku, hostinger, aws basically you can use any and also with that hosting you will get an `ip` for that `hosting` and that `ip will work every instead of local host`.

Yes that ip will also work in google play store app.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I appreciate your help. so after the deploy I'll get an ip , and I need to add it in my code instead of localhost ... right ?

Comment: yes on flutter side you have to use that ip

Comment: +1 for Heroku, you need a few tweaks to use their deploy utilities (CLI, automatic install etc), but they have a free and simple plan for this

Answer (score 0):

Especially if you lack any experience deploying, consider using Laravel Forge https://forge.laravel.com. It is made for Laravel and will massively simplify the deployment and take a lot of configuration needs of your back.